# Nuxt + axios ...how to add {{this.$route.params}} in axios url?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Hello im trying to add {{this.$route.params}} to my axios url for get the data on dedicated profil pages.
here is the part i want to add in axios url the "id" :
[image]

The Axios code from 'RikLamers' who explain me how to get data, it is where i want to add "this.$route.params" :

```
 data() {
  return {
    results: [],
  }
},
 async  mounted() {
  await axios.get(`API url" ${to.params.id}`)
.then(response => {this.results = response.data.content})

 },
```

but i mistake somewhere, hope someone can explain me ?

Comment: Do you want to fetch the data based on route params?

Comment: Yes it is that :) i need to add "id" like aurelie-wulff-2 to my axios get url

Comment: Cool, Below answer  will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access URL param using `this.$route.params.id`. Use `try catch`, when you use `await`.

```
data() {
  return {
    results: [],
  }
},
async  mounted() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`[Your API URL]/${this.$route.params.id}`)
    this.results = response.data.content
  catch (e) {}
},
```

Comment: Thank you im trying right now but i get an error with the catch syntax error

Comment: Maybe i forget to close it ?   catch (e) {}
},

Comment: Thank you Prime its working great i just add   this.results = response.data.content}
  catch (e) {console.error(error)}
}, and no more error ...Thanks again